# why isn't simple javascript string compare working?

Tags: javascript, string-comparison

I am trying to do a simple javascript string compare, yet nothing seems to work. My .ajax reads a db table and returns strings. I then compare each string to the .text() value by looping through my UI checkboxes using jQuery. When the two strings match, I want to use jQuery to check the checkbox that has the matching string. Both types of variables at typeof "string".

Things I've tried in code, either do not show matching strings as being equal, or sometimes it shows that every string is equal, even when they do not appear to be equal. These things I've tried, some in the console, usually rendering "Undefined". I've searched and researched and tried things to no avail. Stumped. I've tried:

==, ===, multiplying *1, using toLowerCase(), toUpperCase(), trim(), valueOf(), eval, toString().

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index) {          
    var question_id = data[index].question_id;
    var question_text = data[index].question_text;

    for (i = 1; i <= 25 ; i++) { //checkbox element uses i as part of its id.
        checkbox_text = jQuery('#ocCheckBox' + i).text(); //checkbox text
        if (question_text == checkbox_text) {
            //jQuery('#ocCheckBox' + i).jqxCheckBox('checked', true);
            console.log(
                "id/text: " + i + "/" + question_id + "/" + question_text + " =? #ocCheckBox" + i + ": " + jQuery('#ocCheckBox' + i).text()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to compare 2 strings, when they match then check the box using jQuery. Instead either the strings render as unequal all the time, or equal all the time.

Edited ex post facto: i cannot make the code reproduceable because it grabs data from a remote server - it's as simple as:

```
if(question_text == checkbox_text).
```

my .ajax calls a .php file doing a Select which returns a json_encode array.
the

```
jQuery.each(data, function(index)
```

cycles through the "data" grabbing the text like this:

```
var question_text = data[index].question_text;
```

console.log shows this to be a typeof = string.
console.log shows the text to be: "Improved access to high quality care."

Next, i cycle through all the checkboxes [corrected my posting from $EOCQ_OCcount var to simply 25 - the # of checkboxes].

I grab the text() of each UI checkbox like this, as shown in my code:

```
checkbox_text = jQuery('#ocCheckBox' + i).text();
```

console.log shows checkbox_text to be typeof string.
console.log shows checkbox_text text: "Improved access to high quality care.".

So, now it shows question_text and checkbox_text are both "string" and both contain "Improved access to high quality care.".

Then I compare question_text from the db with the checkbox_text using this:

```
if(question_text == checkbox_text) { ... THIS is where it does not compare the strings properly.
```

Hope this helps, and again thank you for your attention to this, still stumped.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] in a runnable Stack Snippet - we cannot see what your `data` is, or what is echoed by your `$EOCQ_OCcount` from here

Comment: FYI you were given a question ban for a reason. You should have learned from that. Please read [ask] — you haven't provided any ability to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Could you try logging the values of `question_text` and `checkbox_test` to see their values before the comparison? This way you can at least confirm for yourself what values are actually being compared, and it might give you a hint on where to start.

Comment: `jQuery('#ocCheckBox' + i).text()` ???  Does a checkbox even return a value for text() ?  You might have to use val() or attr("value").

Comment: Are you sure the strings are the same? Note that `"hello"` and `" hello"` and `"hello "` are all different. Whitespace matters and this includes newlines and tabs in your HTML

Comment: I recommend just adding `console.log` calls before the string comparison so you can see what values you're getting. Chrome/Webkit's debugger might help as well (Sources tab) with its breakpoints, which allow you to see the values of variables by hovering over them when the script is paused, and its logpoints, which let you add extra code at specific lines without modifying the actual script server-side.

Comment: in this case my code uses server info; and the reproduceable code would literally be if(str1 == str2) format. also, i logged the vars as requested above. sscotti, yes the .text() returns the text. val and attr('value') returns "undefined". slebetman, i tried trim to no avail. HewwoCraziness, yes i've been using console to display the text values.

Comment: jhpratt, this at least shows my live code, but not runnable due to it's grabbing info from a server so not "reproduceable"; but the code dynamics are complete. my first jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dcparham/wn791hze/6/

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to check to see if two strings are equal, then your string comparison:

```js
if(question_text == checkbox_text) ...
```

should be fine.

I'd need to see more of your code to help more, especially since I'm not too familiar with jQuery. But what I'd do is check to make sure both variables are strings.

I also feel like you should be able to do this without using jQuery. I would do something like:

```html
<input type = "checkbox" id = "item1"><p>item1</p>
<input type = "checkbox" id = "item2"><p>item2</p>
```

and then have:

```js
var items = [
"item1",
"item2"
];

var valid = false;
var x;

while (!valid) { // This loop just forces valid input.
   x = input() // Or however you want to handle user input.
   if (items.includes(x)) {
      valid = true;
   }
}

for (item of items) {
   if (x == item) {
      document.getElementById(item).checked = true;
   }
}
```

It's annoying because it forces you to put all the IDs into an array, but it's simple, and works.

Comment: something similar occurred to me, and i like your idea. looking into it.

Comment: cannot format down here but i tried your suggestion and still get no comparison. here is my new code, replete with commented out code, and documentation to indicate other things i have tried. hope this works, my first jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/dcparham/wn791hze/6/

Answer (score 0):

ALL - the answer involved some of what you all said, but in short here's the trick:

Used typeof to determine each was in fact a string.
Used .length() to determine why each string was't exactly the same.n
Used .trim() to make them the same length - >>>this solved my problem<<<.

I also used localeCompare() with the 2 strings in case simple == wasn't reliable
I also used valueOf() to return the primitive value of a String object.

Thank you, All for your help with this maddening problem!